# How to make an arrow function a method in a Javascript Class?

Tags: javascript

It just occured to me that:

```
class Jamie {
    method function(){
        .... //Is a method
    }

    notAMethod = () => {
        ....//Is not a method?
    }
}
```

I am clearly confused in the matter, but why can't I use arrow functions and maintain the context of `this = Jamie`? Instead of using `bind` to keep context?

Comment: No, that's a class property assigned to an arrow function. It itself is not a method.

Comment: It's not part of ES6, as it's still a proposition , but you can use babel's [Class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to do that.

Comment: So indeed its not a method and just a property, this is bad practise imo. As it will cause unexpected behaviour. Yet so tempted for my being lazy.

Comment: When you do `this.method = this.method.bind(this)` you get a property as well. Using arrow functions is shorter, and more expressive.

Comment: `method function(){…}` is not exactly valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `constructor` function and `this` keyword to assign those methods and have the right `this` working without any `bind`s.

```js
class Jamie {
    constructor () {
        this.getContext = () => {
            console.log(this) // returns Jamie
        }
    }
}
new Jamie().getContext()
```

In the example above, `getContext` will return `Jamie` class as it's `this`.